# PHP Google Drive API authentication not required

Tags: php, authentication, google-api, google-drive-api

I am developing a PHP code that uses Google drive API. The API can upload files when your Google account that owns the drive were logged-in. My question is that is it possible that it can upload files even if the google account that owns it did not loggeg-in like for example, no google account were logged-in or other google account were logged-in. I just want to make the drive is public that anyone can upload files.

this is the code that I used.

```
<?php

  function setGoogleDriveUpload($clientID, $secretKey, $redirecturi, $newfilename, $uploadfile){
    session_start();
    $url_array = explode('?', 'http://'.$_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $url = $url_array[0];
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';   

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($clientID);
    $client->setClientSecret($secretKey);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirecturi);
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
       $_SESSION['accessToken'] = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
       header('location:'.$url);exit;
    } elseif (!isset($_SESSION['accessToken'])) {
       $client->authenticate();
    }

    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
    $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $file = new Google_DriveFile();

    $file_path = $uploadfile;
    $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
    $file->setTitle($newfilename);
    $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
    $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
    $service->files->insert(
        $file,
        array(
            'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
            'mimeType' => $mime_type
        )
    );

    finfo_close($finfo);

}
```

Comment: "no google account were logged-in or other google account were logged-in" that statement doesn't even make a little bit of sense want to try again?  please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"My question is that is it possible that it can upload files even if the google account that owns it did not logged-in"**

Yes, provided the account owner granted offline access. In that case your app will have received a Refresh Token, which you store and use to generate an Access Token when you want to upload a file.